# Testing a server using Python script

Tags: python

I want to do conformance testing of thttpd server. I need to use the python scripts to test it.

Can you please share a script to test the transmission and reception of data to the server?

Also, what kind of possible tests need to be performed? Are there any specific parameters to be tested?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done simply using the builtin urllib

```
urllib.urlopen(yourserveraddress).read()
```

You can also do other things with urllib2 that allow you to test more functionality.

If you want some more intence tests then you might want to build a twisted reactor to test all your functionality.